# (La)TeX Subsystems for Labplot (KDE)

Tags: pdftex, texlive, linux

I am currently trying to generate some nice graphics with [LabPlot](https://labplot.kde.org/). In the axis description, I would like to add in-depth greek symbols, and I saw that there is a LaTeX option. I also found the settings to choose the TeX subsystem. I can't select any as LabPlot doesn't seem to find any of the subsystems. The documentations do not contain any further information on this topic, they merely state that it is possible to use different subsystems at the same time.

I am using the most current version of TeXLive, the necessary paths are contained in the $PATH variable.

I'm honestly not even sure if this belongs here, but I wouldn't know where it would belong otherwise. Searches have not turned up anything useful, there doesn't seem to be any guide explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 22.04LTS is using LabPlot 2.8 which is already quite old. Our current release is 2.10. we had issues with finding the proper location of the installation of TeXLive which was fixed in the later releases. Can you please check https://labplot.kde.org/download/ for how to get the current release and try out again? For example you can try out the flatpak package: https://flathub.org/apps/org.kde.labplot2
If you have any further questions you can also ask in the labplot forum: https://discuss.kde.org/tag/labplot

Comment: I unistalled version 2.8 which I got from the package manager and installed version 2.10.0 via snap. It still tells me "No LaTeX installation found or selected. LaTeX typesetting not possible".